# How can I change the color of default rounds during UITableView Multiple selection?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multipleselection

```
@IBAction func selectItemTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView?.setEditing(true, animated: false)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

These rounds of a checkmark.
[image: Checkmark sample image]

Comment: By "rounds" you mean the filled circles around your checkmarks? That looks like custom images to me. Can you edit your question to show how you add those colored checkmarks to your table view cells? Also, what do you want to do to those checkmarks? Do you want them to change color when their cells are selected? To what color? And what about a multiple selection where some of the cells show checked and some show unchecked? What should the coloring of those checked/unchecked cells be?

Comment: Thank you @DuncanC for your responce. This is tableView default selection checkmarks.  I mean these gray circles. I want that circles also make green.

Comment: @DuncanC I add these checkmarks via this button in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of those circles, you need to change the *Tint color* of the tableview. You can do this both in the interface builder and in the runtime programmatically.
You can change it whenever you wish, however if you wish to set it only once when your view controller shows up, better do it in `viewDidLoad` method. The choice is yours depending on your need.

This how you can change it programmatically:

```
tableView.tintColor = UIColor.green
```

To do it in the interface builder follow the steps below:

1. Make sure your tableview is selected in the interface builder.

[image]

2. Open up the inspector panel. Then select the attribute inspector where you can modify tableview's attributes.

[image]

3. In the attribute inspector, there is a **View** section at the bottom. You will see a **Tint** attribute in the **View** section. Select the color you wish.

[image]

4. Finally test it. You should see those circles will be tinted with your desired color.

[image]